# Trouble getting POST input trough jQuery Dual Boxes in Django 2.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

i'm using [THIS](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Responsive-jQuery-Dual-Select-Boxes-For-Bootstrap-Bootstrap-Dual-Listbox.html) script to select multiple options in my Django Project. My code is like this:

```
<form method="POST" id="demoform" action="/gestionPDD/HabilitarPDD" > {% csrf_token %}
  <select multiple="multiple" size="10" name="duallistbox_demo1[]" title="duallistbox_demo1[]">
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3" selected="selected">Option 3</option>
    <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="option6" selected="selected">Option 6</option>
    <option value="option7">Option 7</option>
    <option value="option8">Option 8</option>
    <option value="option9">Option 9</option>
    <option value="option0">Option 10</option>
    <option value="optionA">Option 10</option>
    <option value="optionB">Option 10</option>
    <option value="optionV">Option 10</option>
    <option value="optionD">Option 10</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Submit data</button>
</form>
<script>
  var demo1 = $('select[name="duallistbox_demo1[]"]').bootstrapDualListbox();
  $("#demoform").submit(function() {
    alert($('[name="duallistbox_demo1[]"]').val());
    return false;
  });

</script>
```

The problem is when you click submit button, a pop-up confirmation appears and when you click SEND nothing happens. My views are okay, and server doesn't get any response from that button.

If you change the return value in the script (False to True) it actually works and server get a POST request (with all selected options), but you can't cancel the pop-up; When you click submit button and check in the pop-up if you select something wrong you can't go back, the request is sent anyway.

Any idea of how to fix it?

Comment: If you want to return something based on how you exit the alert, check out Javascript's "confirm" function, which does what you want it to.

Comment: Problem keeps the same with confirm. If you set the return value to true, even if you click CANCEL it send the request anyways.

Comment: Right, but you can say `to_return = confirm("what you want to ask"); return to_return`. If to_return is False, then it won't post.

Comment: Point is you store and then use the value of confirm.

Comment: Thanks so much, finally i got it right. The return is like this: 
return confirm($('[name="duallistbox_demo1[]"]').val());

Answer (score 0):

Use `confirm($('[name="duallistbox_demo1[]"])` instead of `alert()`.

This will give you the option to cancel the window.

[More here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp)